# Create random 2d array of char in c++ segmentation fault error

Tags: c++, arrays, char, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to create a function in C++ that returns a 2D array of specific, random letters. Another function is used to get user input, like the length of the array. The code below compiles, but yields a segmentation fault(core dumped) error.

```
char** createGrid () { 
    srand(time(NULL)); //INIT RANDOM SEED
    int rd;
    char** grid[widthHeight];
    rd = rand() % 4;
    char letters[5] = { 'E', 'G', 'R', 'F', 'B' } ;
    for(int i = 0; i < widthHeight-1; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < widthHeight-1; j++) {
            **grid[i] = letters[rd];
            cout << grid[i] << endl;
            **grid[j] = letters[rd];
            cout << grid[j] << endl;

        } //for

    } //for
    return *grid; //idk why need *
} 

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    getInput();
    createGrid();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`char** grid[widthHeight];` - array of pointers, no memory allocated for actual data.

`**grid[i] = letters[rd];` - trying to write to non existing memory

Try to allocate memory.

Not clear why you need `char **` ? Why not just

```
char grid[widthHeight]; //memory allocated
```

and return char *, which is just "grid".

Answer (score -1):

char** grid[widthHeight]; is local variable and will be destroyed after exit from the function. Try to make it static at least.

Answer (score -2):

You need to allocate memory.

You used 2d pointer and one array which makes pretty confusing, but please try it with inserting following code:

```
......
rd = rand() % 4;

for(i=0; i<widthHeight; i++) {
    grid[i] = (char **) malloc(widthHeight*sizeof (char *));
}

for(j=0; j<widthHeight; j++) {
    for(k=0; k<widthHeight; k++) {
        grid[j][k] = (char *)malloc(widthHeight*sizeof (char));
    }
}

char letters[5] = { 'E', 'G', 'R', 'F', 'B' } ;
......
```

Comment: this doesn't create a random grid containing the letters, and though it compiles, still returns a segmentation fault error